# how to disable outlook blank subject prompt in C#

Tags: c#

I want to disable default outlook subject pop up because its making subject optional.I want to have my own pop up which makes the subject mandatory. I am outlook developer and using C#.Net. Can anyone tell me how can i disable outlook blank subject pop up in C#?

Thanks,
Nidhi

Comment: What version of Outlook?

Answer (score 1):

Add a handler to the [`ItemSend`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865076.aspx) event and set the `Cancel` property to `True` if the subject is blank (telling the user that the subject is mandatory of course).

Comment: This does not work for me. ItemSend event handler is not getting called after clicking on send.